# Python лексикографическая нумерация

Tags: python, лексический-анализатор

Программа переводит порядковый номер слова из набора всех возможных слов данного алфавита(в данном примере русского алфавита) в само это слово. Например, 34 слово - это "аа". Но если брать, например 33 слово - а, или кратное 33 слово, например 66, 99 и т.д., то всё ломается из за условия while. Как это можно исправить?

```
letters = {1: 'а',
           2: 'б',
           3: 'в',
           4: 'г',
           5: 'д',
           6: 'е',
           7: 'ё',
           8: 'ж',
           9: 'з',
           10: 'и',
           11: 'й',
           12: 'к',
           13: 'л',
           14: 'м',
           15: 'н',
           16: 'о',
           17: 'п',
           18: 'р',
           19: 'с',
           20: 'т',
           21: 'у',
           22: 'ф',
           23: 'х',
           24: 'ц',
           25: 'ч',
           26: 'ш',
           27: 'щ',
           28: 'ъ',
           29: 'ы',
           30: 'ь',
           31: 'э',
           32: 'ю',
           33: 'я'}


def lx_x(word_num):
    nums = []
    while word_num % 33 > 0:
        nums.append(word_num % 33)

        word_num = word_num // 33

    nums.reverse()

    res = ""
    for i in nums:
        res = res + (letters.get(i))
    return res

print(lx_x(34)) //"аа" на русском
```

Comment: у тебя условие while неправильное - сделай просто word_num>0, и прибавлять нужно будет не остаток, а остаток плюс 1, так как у тебя индексация с 1, то при делении 33 на 33 и другое кратное остаток будет 0, но тебе надо брать первое число.

Comment: так?
     def lx_x(word_num):
    nums = []
    while word_num > 0:
        nums.append((word_num % 33) + 1)

при аргументе 33 выдает "ба"

Comment: точно неправильно сказал. не плюс один надо, а если остаток равен нулю - то возвращать надо 33.

nums.append(word_num % 33 if word_num%33>0 else 33)

Comment: Так? https://ideone.com/tVJ2Of На выходе выдает "ая" при аргументе 33

Comment: в общем у тебя проблема в коде в том, что для обозначения нуля у тебя нет буквы никакой, а при переводе из числовой системы в буквы будут нулевые элементы,

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде правильно вот такой код работает. Вся проблема в том, что у тебя нет для обозначения нулевого индекса буквы никакой.

```
def lx_x(word_num):
    nums = []
    while word_num > 0:
            nums.append(word_num % 33 if(word_num%33>0) else 33)
            word_num = word_num//33 if(word_num%33>0) else word_num//33-1
    nums.reverse()

    res = ""
    for i in nums:
        res = res + (letters.get(i))
    return res
```

Comment: большое спасибо!